# Swift Firebase completion handler not working, not fetching Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I have my function here which is supposed to pull all the locations under the child "launch" in my database.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class SearchSelectVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var locationPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLB: UILabel!

    var locData: [String] = [String]()
    var dateData : [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initPickers()
        getloc(onCompletion: { (data) in
            print(data)
            self.locData = (data)
        })

    }
    func getDate(onCompletion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
        var data : [String] = []
        let selectedLoc = locationLB.text
        var dateRef: DatabaseReference!
        dateRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch").child((selectedLoc)!)
        dateRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("date = \(key)")
                //print(data)

            }
            onCompletion(data)
        }
    }
    func getLoc(onCompletion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void){
        print("here3")
        var data : [String] = []
        var locRef: DatabaseReference!
        locRef = Database.database().reference()
        print("here4")
        locRef.child("launch").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                print(snap)
                print(key)
                data.append(key)
                print("location = \(key)")
                //print(data)

            }
            onCompletion(data)

        }



    }
    func initPickers(){
        locationPicker.delegate = self
        locationPicker.dataSource = self
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

None of the `"here"` statements get printed out, neither the snapshot of key or the data which is being collected. Im not really sure whats wrong with my code. Here is a picture of my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvkya.png) 
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't see "here3" which is simply the first statement in your function then something else is going on

Comment: Am i calling the functions incorrectly?

Comment: @PauloMattos I added added a picture of the Database structure

Comment: @PauloMattos in my view did load, I can edit it to show my whole file if you would like.

Comment: @PauloMattos all the code which has to do with grabbing the location is there now